# Custom highlight to jqPlot stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

When adding a custom highlight to the jqPlot chart, I simply use

```
$('#chart').bind('jqplotDataHighlight', function (ev, sIndex, pIndex, data) {
    var chart_top = $('#chart').offset().top,
        y = plot1.axes.yaxis.u2p(data[1]); // convert y axis units to pixels
    $('#tooltip').css({ top: chart_top + y });
}
```

as seen in the last example [here](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bubble-plots.php). This works great on my simple bar chart. I then try the same on a stacked bar chart, and the x-values are off. Does anyone know how I can get these values or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out how I do a custom tooltip on my stacked bar chart.

[The jsfiddle sample is available here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/RNPxQ/)