# jqplot line - tooltip

Tags: javascript, tooltip, line, jqplot

I'd like to add a vertical line which will display a tooltip when hovering on it. I'd like to flag a company event this way however I can't really find a way to that with JqPlot.

Thanks in advance,
Lashus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for this one you might use the approach I used to provide a line highlight option in `jqPlot`, [details of which are in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11468833/613495) There you have the algorithm for detection when the mouse is over a line.

When you detect that the mouse just entered a line and the tooltip is not visible then build it and show it. Also do not forget to hide the tooltip when mouse moves out of the line. [When implementing this part you will certainly find useful the code from this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10688315/613495)
 It shows how to add a custom tooltip on a stacked bar chart, but the code could be easily adopted to your needs.

***PS:*** I assumed that the vertical line will be at some point drawn on some canvas by you (your code). If it is something else that you had on your mind saying `vertical line` then please explain. Otherwise good luck. :)