# jqplot bar Chart mouse over effect

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I wish to include to tooptip div right above the value of my bar chart

eg: If the bar values around 90,80
On mouse-over the [value box] should be right above the value of the current bar chart.

Is it possible to get the mousey at the bar's starting top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just browsed trough, It can be accessed via

```
x = plot1.axes.xaxis.u2p(data[0]),  // convert x axis unita to pixels
y = plot1.axes.yaxis.u2p(data[1]);  // convert y axis units to pixels
```

Comment: Just like you are saying this methods should help you achieve what you want (+1). For an example of the way I use these in [a stacked bar chart to make my custom tooltip please see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10688315/613495).