# Keyboard event left/right arrow in jqPlot

Tags: events, jqplot, keypress, keydown

I would like to make a tooltip that will respond to the keys (left / right). How do I add an event in a similar way:

```
$.jqplot.eventListenerHooks.push(['jqplotClick', handleClick]);
```

I need to get the 'plot' object in event.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start by [checking out one of my other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10434535/613495) and see the code sample there. It presents a way of listening for keyboard events.
It comes down to the following code:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        //on left arrow key down 
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        //on right arrow key down
    }
});
```

*Remember that to have the sample respond to keys the 'Result' area on the jsfiddle must be selected.*

Personally, for the tooltip I would use a custom one, to have a better control over it. How to do it is, for example, presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10688315/613495).